# How to extend session timeout duration period?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, iis-6

We have developed an ASP.Net Web Application. In its web.config file, we have set the session timeout period is 60 as below:

```
    <sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="60"/>
```

But still, the session expired within 15 minutess. I don't want to expire the session up to 1 hour. How to extend the session timeout period up to 1 hour? I need all your suggestions.

Comment: Check if your `Session.Timeout` is set to a lower value in code

Comment: In Coding, I didn't set session timeout value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
The application pool’s worker process default idle timeout is also set to 20 minutes
The default mode of storing session state is in the IIS process
```

So you should try to change the application pool,s worker process default time out

Here is the [link](http://asp-net.vexedlogic.com/2012/05/23/aspasp-net-session-timeout-how-do-i-change-it/).

Answer (score 0):

You need to increase IIS session state timeout.  This might be set to override `<sessionState>`.
Read the following - [Configure Session Time-out (IIS 7)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725820%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

just increase time in **Timeout** and this time is in minutes so convert the hours into minutes and set it as follow in web.config.

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="60"/>
```

You can follow the below link
http://forums.asp.net/t/1452762.aspx

read this above link i hope this will work for you...

Comment: I think timeout is set in minutes and not seconds in this case: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9(v=vs.71).aspx